# Equivalent C# cryptograph in react native

Tags: c#, react-native, cryptography, aes

I am looking for a ReactNative equivalent for the following C# Crypto methods. Basically, I am calling a C# API endpoint that requires Json calls to be encrypted. Its also sending back encrypted results using the same Cryptography. The C# methods where provided by my client.

I am fairly new to ReactNative as such I have been unable to successfully reproduced the methods in ReactNative.

I have looked at similar functions online such as one highlighted [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-C-Sharp-with-aes-algorithm-i/) but to no avail.

I will higly appreciate your help.

### C# METHODS

```
public string EncryptFromDataObject(string jsonString)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MySecret.sInitVector);

            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(MySecret.sPassPhrase, null);

            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(MySecret.iKeySize / 8);

            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            memoryStream.Close();

            cryptoStream.Close();


            //string s = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);     // base64 without padding
            //s = s.PadRight(s.Length + (s.Length * 3) % 4, '=');  // add padding

            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }

        //Decrypt
        public string DecryptToDataObject(string cipherDataObj)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MySecret.sInitVector);

            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherDataObj);

            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(MySecret.sPassPhrase, null);

            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(MySecret.iKeySize / 8);

            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

            memoryStream.Close();

            cryptoStream.Close();


            string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);


            return jsonString;
        }
```

Comment: What was wrong with the functions you linked?

Comment: The default padding more is different in c# from json.  You need to add a statement to change padding.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Rebert  When I carry out a test encryption I am getting  instead of encrypted string System.Byte[]

Comment: The encryption is simply AES in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding. But the real problem might be `PasswordDeriveBytes`, which derives a key from the password. For returns up to the hash output size this corresponds to PBKDF1, otherwise a proprietary MS extension is used. Which of these applies here depends on `MySecret.iKeySize`. `PasswordDeriveBytes` uses SHA1 as digest and 100 as iteration count by default.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed though not by using the above C# class but used the implementation [here](https://github.com/yeyintkoko/encrypt-decrypt-c--nodejs).

I managed to encrypt from C# and decrypt using ReactNative and vise-versa. The only catch is to make sure that the iv value used in ReactNative is generated is obtained from C# code.